# class label in bootstrap acting weird

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The label is acting weird. It is not following the parent width !

The width of the parent div is `.col-2 {
width: 16.666666666666664%;
}`
, But when label div is added to it, labels break out of the parent div.

check this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Anenth/ADukg/3799/)

*Problem solved when i modified the code* `.label{
    white-space:normal;
}`

I want to know why bootstrap used `.label{
    white-space:nowarp;
}`
Ya i got it ! they set it as white-space nowarp so that labels with 2 or more words will in one line

Comment: Why not? That's just the definition they chose

Comment: There should be a reason for setting white-space to nowarp !

Comment: Ya i got it ! they set it as white-space nowarp so that labels with 2words will in one line

Comment: That's what `white space: nowrap` does...